# MongoDB editing a document

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Firstly let me explain what I am working with.
So I have a collection of userProfiles that are modeled like in the plnkr.
I am also have a function that is being passed a array of edited topics. I then need to search the userProfiles collection for a matching topicID and replace the topics section of the document. Not the entire document. I know of the `collection.replace()`. But that replaces the entire document. I need to replace just like half of it. So maybe I need to use `findOneAndUpdate()`? Im not sure. I am new to Mongo.. I have made a plnkr for code reference. [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/elF3CGecLHBtHYPzlrTm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) for this.

```
db.userProfiles.update(
   { "UserTopics.topicID": "abc"},
   { $set: { "UserTopics.$": editedTopic } }
)
```

Comment: What exactly is the .$ doing inside "UserTopics.$"?

Comment: @AustinHunter, Using "UserTopics.topicID" you are going to match an element in an array. So $ represents the element you selected by '"UserTopics.topicID": "abc"' .

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to replace the topics you can simply use the [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db-collection-update) method. And if you need to edit more than one userProfile, set [multi](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) to true (in case more than one user has the desired topicId).

Comment: I've never seen multi before, looks like exactly what I need. Awesome. I'll give this a try.